# Two level extending of User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a `Django` project. There are two types of users. First type - Customer (UserProfile) is an extended built-in `User` because everybody has to have stored it's *telephone*, *address* etc. But there is another type of `User` called `Translator`. The translator has all permissions and attributes like Customer (UserProfile) and some new attributes - `Languages`,`Prices` etc.

I've chosen a probably most common way to handle a `UserProfile`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    ...
```

Now, I want to create `Customer` profile. I can't decide whether I should extend `User` (every user has already `UserProfile`) or to extend `UserProfile` itself.

So the option A is:

```
class TranslatorUserProfile(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(User)
    languages ...
    ...
```

And option B is:

```
class TranslatorUserProfile(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)
    languages ...
    ...
```

Translator will be able to access more pages than regular `User` which is a `UserProfile` and will be of course more attributes.

Is there some pattern? What should I do?

Comment: Have you thought about just using groups and setting custom permissions on the group rather than multiple user types?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, your translator extends the common user. In order to keep the db tables of both separate, you can make both subclass an abstract base model that defines their common attributes:

```
class AbstractUserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='%(class)s')
     telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     ...

     class Meta:
          abstract = True

class UserProfile(AbstractUserProfile):
    pass

class TranslatorUserProfile(AbstractUserProfile):
    languages = ...
```

I have such a structure working fine in a project at work.

Comment: Thanks. What if User want's to become Translator? In this case, I have to create TranslatorUserProfile based on UserProfile and then delete the UserProfile ?

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the way to go in that case.